# How to treat a set of attributes as one attribute html?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a margin for a section of my site but it has multiple attributes and its treating each one individually, Is there any way I can treat it as one attribute. Here's my example:

```
<div style="background-color: grey; padding: 13px;">
    <h1>This part of the site is the menu, this part should be unaffected</h1>
</div>
<div style="float: right;">
    <h1>This part should be closer to the left side</h1>
</div>
<h1>This part should be closer to the right side</h1>
```

I want each side to be closer together, doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: heres the example in html form: https://pste.eu/p/BOWN.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: with float right you are positioning the second div to the right side of the page not the left

Comment: what did you want to do can you please explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

style:

```css
.flex{display:flex; justify-content: space-around}
```

html:

```html
<div style="background-color: grey; padding: 13px;"><h1>This part of the site is the menu, this part should be unnafected</h1></div>
<div class="flex">
    <div>
        <h1>This part should be closer to the left side</h1> 
    </div>
    <div>
         <h1>This part should be closer to the right side</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```